# Using Ruby Sinatra, @tasks.each do |task| requires check for defined?(task)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I am checking out Sinatra using this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/just-do-it-learn-sinatra-i/).  In the index method, it selects all tasks:

```
@tasks = Task.all
```

In the index view, it iterates all of those tasks:

```
- @tasks.each do |task|
```

And, in the task partial, it displays the name:

```
= task.name
```

As expected, the task partial iterates through the entire Task class, but it continues past the last task and finally fails:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `task' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x4e0db18>:
```

This happens within the each iteration unless I test whether task, the each variable, is defined?

```
- if defined?(task)
```

This is unexpected, to me.  Can someone explain it?

Main.rb:

```
# https://www.sitepoint.com/just-do-it-learn-sinatra-i/
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter'

DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'sqlite3:development.db')
class Task
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,           Serial
  property :name,         String, :required => true
  property :completed_at, DateTime
end
DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

get '/' do
  @tasks = Task.all
  slim :index
end

post '/' do
  Task.create  params[:task]
  redirect to('/')
end

get '/:task' do
  @task = params[:task].split('-').join(' ').capitalize
  slim :task
end

delete '/task/:id' do
  Task.get(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect to('/')
end

put '/task/:id' do
  task = Task.get params[:id]
  task.completed_at = task.completed_at.nil? ? Time.now : nil
  task.save
  redirect to('/')
end
```

index.slim:

```
form action="/" method="POST"
  input type="text" name="task[name]"
  input.button type="submit" value="New Task >>"

h2 My Tasks

ul.tasks
  - @tasks.each do |task|
    - if defined?(task)
      == slim(:task, locals: { task: task })
```

task.slim:

```
li.task
  - if defined?(task)
    = task.name
    form.update action="/task/#{task.id}" method="POST"
      input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"
      / Logic is bad here and will be fixed.
      - if task.completed_at.nil?
        input type="submit" value="  " title="Complete Task"
      - else
        input type="submit" value="✓" title="Uncomplete Task"
    form.delete action="/task/#{task.id}" method="POST"
      input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"
      input type="submit" value="&times;" title="Delete Task"
```

Comment: What line produces the error? Can you include the backtrace? Can you also provide the code that produces the error (you say using `defined?` fixes it, so this code won’t produce the error)?

Comment: @matt  The error I listed occurred in task.slim on the line '= task.name'.  I added the code '- if defined?(task)' in index.slim and task.slim to prevent the error.  I didn't save the backtrace and am continuing to work through the tutorial.  It could be recreated using the code here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restored the code and attempted to recreate the problem to obtain the stacktrace.  It did not recur.  I can only speculate that there was an error in the database such that it contained an invalid entry resulting in the problem.